# Help me to achieved inheritance in OOP's PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Help me to achieved inheritance in OOP's PHP?

```
class A
{
  protected $a;
  protected $b;
  public $c;    //=>mention here
  protected $d;

  function todo1()
  {
    //more code here 
  }

  private function todo_c()
  {
    //more code here 
  }
}



class C{
  public $c;
  function todo3()
  {
    $this->c = new A;//=>mention here
  }

  //so in C I can do like this 
  function newbie()
  {
    if($this->c->c == 'lenak'){ //=>mention here $this-c->c it is okay
        echo 'I am newbie';
    }
  }
}
```

One more
If I need an object `$_B` will the same object `$_A` except the atrribute `c` and `todo_c()`.
Is it posible for me? or How can I do this?

- Change visibility property `c` of class `A` to private But what about Class `c` `($this->c->c)`
- copy and paste of A to B and delete what we don't need :) !!! (bad ways) so

So I tried with inheritance in php

```
class B extends A
{
    //TODO 
}

$_A = new A; // created object $_A
$_B = new B; // $_B will the same object $_A but except `c` and  `todo_c()`
```

Anybody Could help me please? How we implement class $B ?

Comment: When declaring properties in a PHP class, you need the `$`, as in `public $c`

Comment: trying to understand OOP without a real example isnt' helpful. Write OOP while you are doing your normal code.. you will find it way easly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you might be able to override the scope of the instance variable from public to private, PHP will not let you do it easily. The most easy way is to wrap it, as mentioned above.

By changing the scope of an instance variable from public to private, you are breaking the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which states that any child class should be able to be treated as a parent type. By overwriting this method, you break that Principle, as any method that accesses this public member will not be able to access the private instance in the subclass. Something to keep in mind.

Comment: yes,this is my problems.I do not understand how can I do this with Php?

Answer (score 4):

From what I think you're saying, you'd just overload the "c" and "todo_c()" class members.  For example, your first class would be:

```
class A
{
  protected $a;
  protected $b;
  public $c;
  public function todo_c() {}
}
```

Then your class be would look like:

```
class B extends A
{
 private $c;
 private function todo_c() {}
}
```

I am fairly certain that you can't change the visibility of a class member without re-declaring it.  However you can refer to the parent if you wanted to, which might be useful in your function.  In that case you would do something like:

```
class B extends A
{
 private $c;
 private function todo_c() { parent::todo_c();}
}
```

Comment: Probably what he needs. One caveat: you cannot change the `todo_c` method signature; it needs to be public in derived classes too. (Not that access modifiers make much sense in scripting languages anyway.)